# find declaration in unix dev toolchain

Tags: unix, toolchain

I recently read a lot of opinions on whether or not one should use an IDE or the unix toolchain to develop c++ programs. One thing I was asking myself is if you can somehow follow symbols in gvim or any editor that you like. This is one feature I use in Visual Studio or Eclipse a lot.

Or put in another way. Assume you browse some foreign code and you spot an unknown function name. How do you find out from which library it comes without manually searching all the includes?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two popular tools for finding symbols.

- [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)
- [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)

I believe emacs and vim both have support for those two tools.